# what is the purpose of #: (hashtag/pound colon) in bash

Tags: bash, comments, sh, hashtag

I was recently looking at the Homebrew source code. Since it's a popular tool, the code is probably relatively clean. I noticed they use a `#:` comment style (example: [update.sh](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh)). I haven't seen that anywhere else (and it's hard to search for symbols, so I can't find any mentions of it). Is that an accepted convention? Does it have a special meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be some sort of documentation fragment for a manpage: it is written in standard manpage style and documents the script that follows. This is even more obvious in [`Library/Homebrew/cmd/vendor-install.sh`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cmd/vendor-install.sh#L1-L3), where a similar comment can be found which is tagged with `@hide_from_man_page`:

> ```
> #: @hide_from_man_page
> #:  * `vendor-install` [<target>]:
> #:     Install vendor version of Homebrew dependencies.
> ```

So, presumably, all fragments that are not thusly annotated, are included in the manpage.

You picked an unfortunate example, though, because `update` is considered an "essential command" and is thus documented in a separate section of the manpage. Let's pick a non-essential command such as `style`, which you can find in [`Library/Homebrew/cmd/style.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cmd/style.rbL1-L18):

> ```
> #:  * `style` [`--fix`] [`--display-cop-names`] [<formulae>|<files>]:
> #:    Check formulae or files for conformance to Homebrew style guidelines.
> #:
> #:    <formulae> is a list of formula names.
> #:
> #:    <files> is a list of file names.
> #:
> #:    <formulae> and <files> may not be combined. If both are omitted, style will run
> #:    style checks on the whole Homebrew `Library`, including core code and all
> #:    formulae.
> #:
> #:    If `--fix` is passed and `HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER` is set, style violations
> #:    will be automatically fixed using RuboCop's `--auto-correct` feature.
> #:
> #:    If `--display-cop-names` is passed, the RuboCop cop name for each violation
> #:    is included in the output.
> #:
> #:    Exits with a non-zero status if any style violations are found.
> ```

Now, when you look into [`Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md.erb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md.erb#L4-L7), you can see that they are *indeed* manpage fragments which get automatically included into the main `brew.1` manpage:

> ```
> # To make changes to this man page:
> #
> # - For changes to a specific command (appears in the `COMMANDS` section):
> #   - Edit the top comment in `Library/Homebrew/cmd/<command>.{rb,sh}`.
> #   - Make sure to use the line prefix `#:` for the comments to be recognized as
> #     documentation. If in doubt, compare with already documented commands.
> # - For other changes: Edit this file.
> #
> # When done, regenerate the man page and its HTML version by running `brew man`.
> ```

And [here's the line where they get included into the manpage](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md.erb#L51):

> ```
> <%= commands.join("\n") %>
> ```

You can see the generated output in [`share/man/man1/brew.1`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/man/man1/brew.1#L447-L468):

> ```
> .TP
> \fBstyle\fR [\fB\-\-fix\fR] [\fB\-\-display\-cop\-names\fR] [\fIformulae\fR|\fIfiles\fR]
> Check formulae or files for conformance to Homebrew style guidelines\.
> .
> .IP
> \fIformulae\fR is a list of formula names\.
> .
> .IP
> \fIfiles\fR is a list of file names\.
> .
> .IP
> \fIformulae\fR and \fIfiles\fR may not be combined\. If both are omitted, style will run style checks on the whole Homebrew \fBLibrary\fR, including core code and all formulae\.
> .
> .IP
> If \fB\-\-fix\fR is passed and \fBHOMEBREW_DEVELOPER\fR is set, style violations will be automatically fixed using RuboCop\'s \fB\-\-auto\-correct\fR feature\.
> .
> .IP
> If \fB\-\-display\-cop\-names\fR is passed, the RuboCop cop name for each violation is included in the output\.
> .
> .IP
> Exits with a non\-zero status if any style violations are found\.
> .
> ```

and [`share/doc/homebrew/brew.1.html`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/brew.1.html#L340-L354):

> ```
> <dt><code>style</code> [<code>--fix</code>] [<code>--display-cop-names</code>] [<var>formulae</var>|<var>files</var>]</dt><dd><p>Check formulae or files for conformance to Homebrew style guidelines.</p>
>
> <p><var>formulae</var> is a list of formula names.</p>
>
> <p><var>files</var> is a list of file names.</p>
>
> <p><var>formulae</var> and <var>files</var> may not be combined. If both are omitted, style will run
> style checks on the whole Homebrew <code>Library</code>, including core code and all
> formulae.</p>
>
> <p>If <code>--fix</code> is passed and <code>HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER</code> is set, style violations
> will be automatically fixed using RuboCop's <code>--auto-correct</code> feature.</p>
>
> <p>If <code>--display-cop-names</code> is passed, the RuboCop cop name for each violation
> is included in the output.</p>
> ```

I don't know whether this is an accepted convention in shell scripting, but similar conventions are used across a wide variety of languages and/or documentation tools, e.g. JavaDoc (`/**`), Doxygen (`/**`, `/*!`, `///`, `//!`), JsDoc (`/**`), or C♯ (`///`).