# What does Hash Colon (#:) mean as first line of shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

I have inherited a number of shell scripts on a Centos system which start with `#:` on the first line.

- There is nothing else on the line.
- The scripts will execute properly if run from the command line.  ex;  `$ ./test.sh`
  This is an example of one of the working scripts:

```
#:

DATE=`date +%D::%H:%M`
LOG=/home/alert/bin/log/test.log

echo ${DATE} >> ${LOG}

exit
```

What does #: mean?

I know what a 'normal' shebang means such as #!/bin/sh

I have looked all over the internet and stack overflow and haven't found an answer.  I'm guessing it means "use your shell"?  (ie., #!$SHELL)?

FYI - There is one other question/answer regarding #: imbedded in shell scripts where #: is a type of comment that is included in man files.  In this instance, it does not appear to apply given that this comment only appears on the first line of the file and does not have any following text.

Comment: It means nothing to `bash` itself; there may be some other tool for which a conventional comment beginning with `#:` has some special meaning.

Comment: It's likely not doing anything. A shebang would need to start with `#!`. Maybe it was _meant_ to prevent execution by using a shebang of the builtin command `:`, which does nothing.

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate? [what is the purpose of #: (hashtag/pound colon) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38978159/4518341)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  I read that answer before I asked my question and it is referring to telling man page documentation to not include that particular comment.  In the case of my question, there is no additional text on the line, it's not a comment, and it only every occurs as the first line in the file.

Comment: @Rob OK I agree it's not a duplicate. Although the hash-colon might be for the same purpose, like maybe your scripts were automatically generated with an empy "manpage comment" or whatever you'd call that. To clarify the linked answer, comments with `#:` are used to generate manpages - only the ones with `@hide_from_man_page` are ignored.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `#:`. If the file to be executed is not an ELF (or the like), and it doesn't have a proper shebang, `exec` family functions (except `execlp` and `execvp`) fail; at that point a call like `execlp(file, file)` will be the same as `execlp(<sh>, file, file)`; see [posix spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html#tag_16_111_03)/DESCRIPTION/11th paragraph. Some shells just interpret the script internally without calling `execlp`, `execvp` though. I guess -as Mark said- it's a way of telling *this is a shell script* to both reader, and the kernel

Answer (score 4):

Good question. It is not treated as a shebang; the script appears to run the same way any other script with no shebang is run by the shell: it shows up in `ps` as `bash -himBH` rather than `bash filename`. As far as I can tell, it's just a comment.

It might be the old "hey, this is a shell script!" syntax from before interpreter support via `#!` was added to the `exec` system call: scripts that started with `#:` - actually, probably just `#` or `:` would work - would be recognized as such by the shell itself and executed by it directly rather than by calling `exec`. I can't think of a reason for it on a modern system, though.

Comment: Huh, where could I read more about this? I couldn't find anything from googling `shell "hash colon"` or anything similar.

Comment: There's a mention of it on [the Wikipedia entry for shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#History).